# how to do splash page or index.html first page animation in HTML5

Tags: html, ipad

is there any way to do a flash-like animation for the splash screen for iPad app in HTML5.

i have searched a lot for javascript but did not get anything.

Comment: Animated splash screens? I thought we'd managed to move on from those obscenities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual alternatives to Flash animation are [canvas](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas) (which has its own API) and [SVG](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg) (which is subject to standard DOM manipulation), both of which are supported by iOS Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe is developing an HTML/Javascript/CSS based alternative to Flash Builder called [Adobe Edge](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/), you can download it for free for a limited time for Adobe Labs. It doesn't have nearly as many features as Flash(at least not yet), but it provides enough basic functionality to accomplish what you are asking.